# What is the radius of convergence of:

Tags: complex-analysis

What is the radius of convergence of the series
$$1+z+{z}^2/2^2+z^3/3!+z^4/2^4+z^5/5!+...$$

I used ratio test but then it gives two values of $R$
the values of $R$ are 0 and $\sqrt2$,

Comment: This is $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n!}$? The ratio of the moduli of adjacent terms is $\frac{|z|}{n+1}$, the limit of that is zero regardless of what $z$ is...so I don't know how you are getting "two values" of $R$.

Comment: Sir you are misreading.

Comment: Oh, the intent is clearer now.

Comment: Your function is $\sinh(z)+\frac{4}{4-z^2}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$1 + z + \frac{z^2}{2^2} + \frac{z^3}{3!} + \frac{z^4}{2^4} + \cdots
   = \left(1 + \frac{z^2}{2^2} + \frac{z^4}{2^4} + \cdots\right) + \left(z + \frac{z^3}{3!} + \frac{z^5}{5!} + \cdots \right)$$

We can rearrange terms like this as long as the series is absolutely convergent.  So let's investigate that.  First note that
$$ \left(1 + \frac{z^2}{2^2} + \frac{z^4}{2^4} + \cdots\right) = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \left(\frac{z}{2}\right)^{2n}$$
and
$$ \left(z + \frac{z^3}{3!} + \frac{z^5}{5!} + \cdots \right) = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{z^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$$

Let $R_1$ be the radius of convergence of the first series and $R_2$ be the radius of convergence of the second series.

Apply the ratio test to the first series to get $R_1 = 2$.  Note that if $|z| = 2$ then the first series will diverge.  So the disk of convergence for the first series is all $z \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $|z| < 2$.  Apply the ratio test to the second series to get $R_2 = +\infty$.  So the second series converges on all of $\mathbb{C}$.

We need **both** of these series to be absolutely convergent in order for the original series to converge.  Therefore the original series will converge on the intersection of the domains of convergence for the other two series.  Since the second series converges on all of $\mathbb{C}$ and the first series converges on $\{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| < 2\}$, then the original series converges on $\{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| < 2\}$.  Therefore the radius of convergence of the original series is 2.

EDIT - Verifying $R_1$:

$a_n = \dfrac{z^{2n}}{2^{2n}} = \dfrac{z^{2n}}{4^n}$.  Therefore $a_{n+1} = \dfrac{z^{2n+2}}{4^{n+1}} = \dfrac{z^{2n}z^2}{4^n4}.$

$$\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right| = \left|\frac{z^{2n}z^2}{4^n4} \cdot \frac{4^n}{z^{2n}}\right| = \frac{|z|^2}{4}$$
Take the limit as $n \to +\infty$, still get $|z|^2 / 4$.  Solve $|z|^2 / 4 < 1$ to get $|z| < 2$.

Comment: Why are you including $-2$ in $I_1$? With $z=-2$ you have an infinite sum of $1$...

Comment: Answer is $\sqrt2$ on HS KASANA

Comment: $\sqrt{2}$ doesn't sound right for the problem as presented.

Comment: @kadir, I added verification of $R_1$.

Comment: looks good +1. @kadir the first series is that of $\frac1{1-z^2/4}$ which obviously converges within a radius of $2$, and the second is that of $\sinh(z)$ which converges everywhere.

Comment: Just realized this is complex and not real analysis, so I'll need to update my answer accordingly.